# Run rar for multiple drive query?

Tags: windows, rar

My drive C: has many `bat` files.

So if I want to archive all `bat` files using `rar` I can write :

`rar a -r *.bat bats#.rar`

it is working fine and directory structure is kept.

But I have 4 hard drives.

**Question**

Is it possible to run the same command for specified drives ?

Something like  : ( pseudo)

`rar a -r c:\*.bat+ d:\*.bat+ e:\*.bat + f:\*.e.bat bats#.rar`

I know I can run the command 4 times , but I'm asking if I can do it with a single rar command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rar a -r bats.rar c:\*.bat d:\*.bat
```

If you want to store full paths including drive letter, add the `-ep3` switch.

Comment: What can I say ? you're right. as a husher , I just tried the code without further reading. sorry :-) ( dont shoot me :-))

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked out. :)

Comment: wait.i'm testing the ep3 switch  , just to see how it appears in the rar

Comment: Each drive will appear as a top level folder like C_, D_ etc. When you extract with full paths, the colons will be restored.